# Bash command rev to reverse delemiters

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am working on a shell script that converts exported Microsoft in-addr.apra.txt files to a more useful format so that i can use it in the future in other products for automation purposes. No i am figuring a problem which (im not a programmer) can not solve in a simple way.

Sample script

```
x=123.223.224
rev $x
```

gives me

```
422.322.321
```

but i want to have the output as follow:

```
224.223.123
```

is there a easy way to do it without rev or putting each group in a variable? Or is there a sample i can use? or maybe i use the wrong tools to do it?

Comment: Will your input always have exactly two `.`'s in it? In other words, will it always be of the form `A.B.C` such that the desired result is `C.B.A`, where A, B, and C can have any characters in them *except* `.`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `awk` for this!

If your text file always contains three octets, simply use `.` as separator:

```
echo $x | awk -F. '{ print $3 "." $2 "." $1 }'
```

For more complex cases, use internal `split()`:

```
echo $x | awk '{ 
    n = split($0, a, "."); 
    for(i = n; i > 1; i--) { 
        printf "%s.", a[i]; 
    } 
     print a[1]; }'
```

In this sample `split()` will split every line (which is passed as argument `$0`) using delimiter `.`, saves resulting array into `a` and returns length of that array (which is saved to `n`). Note that unlike C, 
`split()` array indexes are starting with one.

Or `python`:

```
python -c "print '.'.join(reversed('$x'.split('.')))"
```

Comment: @anubhava: do you know other way to count number of dots in line?

Comment: See my answer below, just using `NF`  with proper `FS`.

Comment: @anubhava, oh, I got confused with `i >= 2`. Thanks for the note

Comment: Yes that loop can also be: `for (i=NF; i>1; i--)`

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`:

```
x='123.223.224'
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} {for (i=NF; i>=2; i--) printf $i OFS; print $1}' <<< "$x"
224.223.123
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my script.

```
#!/bin/sh

value=$1
delim=$2
total_fields=$(echo "$value" | tr -cd $2 | wc -c)

let total_fields=total_fields+1

i=1


reverse_value=""
while [ $total_fields -gt 0 ]; do

        cur_value=$(echo "$value" | cut -d${delim} -f${total_fields})
        if [ $total_fields -ne 1 ]; then
                cur_value="$cur_value${delim}"
        fi
        #echo "$cur_value"
        reverse_value="$reverse_value$cur_value"

        #echo "$i --> $reverse_value"

        let total_fields=total_fields-1
done

echo "$reverse_value"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a few small tools.

```
tr '.' '\n' <<< "$x" | tac | paste -sd.
```

```
224.223.123
```